# Wordpress welcome page installation

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site I am woking on and I now cannot get to it.

http://zma.uk.com/zmademo/

It just brings up this page [image attached[image: ]]

Is this normal of have I been hacked?

I've already installed the WP and it was working fine, now this.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe your `wp-config.php` file is missing.

Comment: You move server or any thing else ?

Comment: its been all working fine apart from today.

Comment: I haven't moved a thing, do I need to raise a ticket with the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress welcome page appears (as @Stanimir says in his comment) when wp-config.php file is not present at the root of the WordPress install.

If you have already proceeded to the install, the file has been deleted or moved.

There's no need to do it again, you can copy wp-config-sample.php and modify it with the same db informations and table prefix. 
AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY, and LOGGED_IN_KEY, NONCE_KEY, are used to insure better encryption of information stored in the user's cookies.

The four salts are recommended, but are not required, because WordPress will generate salts for you if none are provided. They are included in wp-config.php by default for inclusiveness.

Save it as wp-config.php and place it in the main WordPress folder.

You can also, verify if the file exists and its permissions, the file permissions for it is 644.

Comment: I spoke to my host, their servers are down.